# Using global variable for option passing?

Tags: python

Here is my problem.

I have a main() that takes in a command line option, say foo, which is a boolean. Then main() calls a bunch of functions, main() calls fcn1(), fcn1() calls fcn2(), fcn2() calls fcn3(), fcn3() calls fcn4(), fcn4() calls fcn5(), then in function fcn5() we reach the place where option foo is used.

I can see two choices to pass this option to fcn5().

First, for every function in the call chain, have a function parameter called foo, and pass foo through these parameters. This looks a bit messy. All functions need to have a function parameter, but for fcn1 - fcn4, they are not really used.

Another choice is to have a global variable, and in main(), I set the global variable g_foo, then in fcn5(), it reads the value of g_foo. But I am not sure whether using global variable in such a case is a good idea.

Do we have some better nice solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify. Does main call fcn1, fcn2, fcn3, fcn4, and fcn5? Or does main call fcn1, which calls fcn2, which calls fcn3, which calls fcn4, which calls fcn5?

Comment: If it's a commandline option, it'll always be available in `sys.argv`, so can't you just grab it from there in `fcn5()`?

Comment: @Aya I am using optparse module. Any way to make it work globally?

Comment: use option 1. more idiomatic py.

Comment: @szli In that case, I'd just assign it to a global 'constant'. If you have lots of parameters, you may want to use some sort of data structure instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make sense to put your functions in a class. Here is a simple example, here the functions don't do anything interesting but could be replaced with your code.

```
import sys

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def fn1(self):
        return self.fn2() # just as a simple example which calls other functions

    def fn2(self):
        return self.fn3()

    def fn3(self):
        return self.fn4()

    def fn4(self):
        return self.fn5()

    def fn5(self):
        return self.arg


def main():
    m = MyClass(arg=sys.argv[1])
    print m.fn1() # prints output based on command line argument


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way you have the benefit of keeping the global in a namespace, and also may keep your overall code tidier.

Comment: Barely beat me to the exact same response!

Comment: I've done this but it feels wrong to me: you're creating an artificial class of a bunch of functions that just happen to need to access to the command line parameters, all just to avoid a single global variable.